# select last child which has not a specified class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this css-selector

```
.buttons:last-child::not(a.hide)

<div class="buttons">
<a href="#tab1">1</a>
<a href="#tab2">3</a>
<a href="#tab3" class="hide">3</a>
</div>
```

I want to select the last child which has not a class of ".hide".

But it does not work. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots is wrong:

- `not` only accepts simple selectors, so either an element *or* a class. For your example, `not(.hide)` should do the job.
- `not(.hide)` is not a pseudo-element, it is a pseudo-class. As such it should be preceded by a single colon, not a double one
- `.button:last-child` does not select the last child of `.buttons`, it selects any element of class `.buttons` that is the last child of its parent.  To select the last `a` in buttons use `.buttons>a:last-child`
- Combining pseudo-selectors requires candidates to match them all.  So `:last-child:not(.hide)` will select elements that are *both* a last child *and* not of class `hide`. Of which you have none. Change the class name in the css or the html and you will match the final element.

In fact I'm not sure you can achieve what you want with pure css.

Comment: okay, thanks for your good explanation. I guess,  I have to use javascript for this case.